# Printing multipage tiff with java

Tags: java, swing, file, printing, tiff

How to print `multipage` `.tiff` file in java ?

I have used
`DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.GIF;` but its not working.
is there any other way or docflavor to print this pageable file ???

This is what we are doing as sample code,

```
public class Printing { 

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{  

 IIORegistry registry = IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance();    
 registry.registerServiceProvider(new com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageWriterSpi());    
 registry.registerServiceProvider(new com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageReaderSpi());     


   String filename = "C:/Users/trainees/Desktop/abcd.TIFF";  
   PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();  
   DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.JPEG;  

   PrintService printService[] =   
   PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(flavor, pras);  
   PrintService defaultService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();  
   PrintService service = defaultService;  

   if (service != null) {  
      DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();  
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);  
      DocAttributeSet das = new HashDocAttributeSet();  
      Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(fis, flavor, das);  
      job.print(doc, pras);  
      Thread.sleep(10000);  
   }  
   System.exit(0);  
}
```

}

Comment: I don't want to convert .tiff files to .pdf file because of the quality purpose.

Comment: You may need to implement a `Printable` and render the image directly, check out [Printing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/) for more details.  Just know that you become responsible for rescaling.  Also, you will need to use `ImageIO` to load the file, but will also need the [JAI ImageIO plugin](https://java.net/projects/jai-imageio) to make it work

Comment: Ya buddy we are using this same thing(printable, JAI) but though it is not printing `.tiff` files.

Comment: You need to get deeper into the Print API, rather then relying on the newer attributes API, you need to get down and dirty and render the image directly to the `Graphics` context using something like `Printable`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `java.awt.print.Book` and append each page to the `Book` using `book.append(this,pageformat,pages);` method. And then printing that will print all the pages of tiff.